# Module matplotlib not being found

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

I've been trying to run matplotlib on Mac, but I always get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'`. I use python3 and MacOX Ventura 13.1.

I've installed matplotlib using `pip3 install matplotlib --user` which produced:

```
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-3.7.1-cp310-cp310-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (7.3 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: contourpy>=1.0.1 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.0 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib) (4.39.3)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.20 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.24.2)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib) (23.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib) (9.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.3.1 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib) (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7->matplotlib) (1.16.0)
Installing collected packages: matplotlib
Successfully installed matplotlib-3.7.1
```

But still gives me the same error!

When I check `type -a python` I get

```
python is an alias for /usr/local/bin/python3
```

But when I go there the folder is empty. I also checked `type -a python3` and I get

```
python3 is /opt/homebrew/bin/python3
python3 is /usr/bin/python3
```

with `type -a pip3`:

```
pip3 is /opt/homebrew/bin/pip3
pip3 is /usr/bin/pip3
```

At this point, I really don't know why I cannot import the matplotlib module. Tried some solutions here but obviously didn't work.

Comment: What about ```type -a pip3```?

Comment: @fdireito nice suggestion. I get `pip3 is /opt/homebrew/bin/pip3
pip3 is /usr/bin/pip3`

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. All packages are installed as precompiled binaries. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/). **If you are using Anaconda, do not use `pip` to install packages that exist within the `conda` ecosystem.** Use `conda install package`. Only use `pip` if the package is not available with `conda install`. Using `pip` can potentially wreck your installation because `pip` and `conda` do not manage dependencies in the same way.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney thank you. I will try that. Why do you recommend Conda over Pip3? Do you think that I should remove the packages in Pip3 before installing it on Conda?

Comment: Anaconda installs to its own directory and runs in it's own environment, so it's not necessary to remove `/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10` unless you want to. I think, since all the packages are precompiled, Anaconda is easier to manage.